The State of White Noise Processes
Assuming we have a  random process indexed by time, and the values assumed by the random process are its state. So a random process  has a discrete or continuous state and a  discrete or continuous time.
In DSP texts, I usually see  the terms “Continuous time white noise” and “Discrete time white noise”.
If I were to think of adding a label about the state,
would these descriptions be accurate:
Discrete time white gaussian noise:
Is a continuous state discrete time process, because each Gaussian RV in the process is continuous
Discrete time white poisson noise:
Is a discrete state discrete time process, because each Poisson RV in the process is discrete.
Seems like an obvious yes, but I haven't seen it explicitly stated anywhere.

What is your question?

In those 2 examples, are my descriptions of their state accurate? "Discrete time white Gaussian noise: Is a continuous state discrete time process" and "Discrete time white Poisson noise: Is a discrete state discrete time process"
